# Infinite loop when reading the text line by line in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, for-loop

I am trying to read 5 lines from the dataset generated in tensorflow from the tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text, but I get stacked in an infinite loop

This is the for loop to read the dataset

```
for ex in all_labeled_data.take(5):
       print(ex)
```

This is the result repeated infinitely:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:0' shape=() dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:1' shape=() dtype=int64>)
(<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_2:0' shape=() dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_2:1' shape=() dtype=int64>)
(<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_3:0' shape=() dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_3:1' shape=() dtype=int64>)
....
(<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_3:0' shape=() dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_3:1' shape=() dtype=int64>)
```

Could you tell me what is wrong? I am using Tensorflow version 1.14.0

Thanks

Comment: Is it due to the list not removing those that have been actioned? so the list is never dropping in size?

Comment: Could you be clearer, please?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Version of Tensorflow v2.0 it works.